# Simple Counting semaphore

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

To understand the working of counting semaphores, i decided to implement a simple version. 
I wanted to verify my current implementation is in fact a correct implementation and i havent missed anything obvious

```
public class CountingSemaphore {
    private int limit;

    public CountingSemaphore(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public synchronized void acquire() {
        try {
            if (limit == 0)
                wait();

            limit--;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void release() {
        try {
            if(limit == 0) 
                notifyAll();

            limit++;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work except for one detail.
Since you use `notifyAll()`, (and as @JBNizet points out, due to the risk of spurious wakeups,) you can wake up several waiting threads, all of which will be freed and decrease `limit`.
Change

```
if (limit == 0)
    wait();
```

to

```
while (limit == 0) {
    wait();
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: +1: I saw the spurious wakeup problem, but missed the obvious logic problem. Duh!

Answer (score 3):

`wait()` should always be enclosed inside a while loop checking for the wakeup condition, due to spurious wakeups. Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) for more information.

Catching Exception, and swallowing them, is a very bad practice. Your `acquire()` method should throw InterruptedException. Your release method shouldn't catch Exception.

And I wouldn't use the semaphore itself as the lock: an external class could use it to synchronize something completely unrelated, and it could lead to bad performance or deadlock. I would use a private final lock object.

Comment: Seems rude to quote and not +1. :)

Answer (score 0):

From a client perspective you should force me to use your semaphore with a value >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem in your code, when you call release you call notify all but here

```
public synchronized void acquire() {
        try {
            if (limit == 0)
                wait();

            limit--;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

all threads that are waiting are released, and you can git limit<0, and you sem breaks
the common solution here is to use loop.

```
 while(limit == 0){
     wait();
}
```